# How to bound <input type="image"> to <input type="text">? Both are in same form

Tags: html, css, input, types, label

When I click on my search image I would like it to be like a label for input text. I don't want to use actual text for label but image. I tried:

```
<input type"text" id="txt"><label for="txt"><input type="image" src="...."></label>
```

but it doesn't do nothing... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>
    <img src="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</label>
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it in the form? If both input type="text" and img is in same form?

Comment: Start with form. The trick is to put your `img` and `input` inside the `label`.

Comment: no it;s not that, when I click on image, it doesn't put cursor in the text field so I can type text.